# Javascript -Merging two JSON ojects isnt working

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, knex.js

Im not erroring, however its not adding the `features` json object to the `results` json object

Code:

```
exports.getApps = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.raw(`
      SELECT *
      FROM APPs
      WHERE VARAPP_PUBLIC_ACTIVE > 0
      ORDER BY VARAPP_PUBLIC_ACTIVE ASC, VARAPP_NAME ASC
    `).then(function(results) {
      if (results[0].length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results[0].length; i++) {
          elaborate(i, results, reject);
        }
        resolve({
          apps: results[0]
        })
      } else {
        resolve({
          error: 'No Apps Found'
        })
      }
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
      reject(err);
    });
  })

  function elaborate(i, results, reject) {
    db.raw(`
        SELECT *
        FROM APPs_Features
        WHERE VARAPP_ID = ?
          ORDER BY VARAPP_ORDER ASC
      `, [results[0][i].VARAPP_ID], i)
      .then(function(features) {
        if (features[0].length > 0) {
          results[0][i].Features = features[0];
        } else {
          results[0][i].Features = null;
        }
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
        reject(err);
      });
  }
}
```

if i `console.log(results[i)` right after the conditional statement within the `.then()` in the `elaborate()` function i get the results json object with the .features, however if i `console.log(results[0]` right before the `resolve()` its gone

Answer (score 0):

This db call in `elaborate` is async isn't it?

```
db.raw(`
        SELECT *
        FROM APPs_Features
        WHERE VARAPP_ID = ?
          ORDER BY VARAPP_ORDER ASC
      `, [results[0][i].VARAPP_ID], i)
```

That means that you are resolving before adding the Features. You need to wait until every db.raw() in each elaborate call is done before you call `resolve({ apps: results[0] })`